# Excel Combination Chart, Moving Secondary Series Alignment

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I'm kind of stuck and would be so appreciative if anyone could help me. I'm trying to move my secondary data series (the circle and diamond data points in the attached image) to be centered over the blue column series (or red when negative) as opposed to centered between the blue and grey series. I'm not sure if there is even a way to accomplish this but I thought I'd throw it out to the experts before I gave up on it.  Also, I'm using Excel 2010 and the chart is technically a pivot-chart.

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to provide!

[image: chart]

Comment: I don't think you can do this, but you could produce [a chart like this instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdVyl.png) if you want centred dots/diamonds? The key would be to make sure your bars remain centred as well.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible as a Pivot Chart (but not too much is).  However, a combination chart can do it quite easily.

1. Plot your four data series on a basic column chart.
2. Change the chart type on your yellow and green series to XY/Scatter type.
3. Add a helper column to your data.  Enter the values 0.625, 1.625, 2.625...7.625.
4. Format your secondary horizontal axis as
   `min = 0`
   `max = 8`
   This will align your primary and secondary axis.
5. Edit your data source for your yellow and green series so that their x values come from the helper column you created.  This should nudge the values over the midpoint of your blue column (0.5 and it's iterations would locate it at the midpoint of your two series).
6. Format to taste.

[image]